# Manipulating Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a `DataFrame A` with one column `location_ms`. I want to split by `;` and `:` to get `DataFrame B`.

DataFrame A(Beginning):

[image: Beginning]

DataFrame B(Final):

[image: Final]

My code below seems to be very roundabout and would love to see a better implementation towards the problem. By doing the splits I create a DataFrame with each element being a list of lists. Then I flatten that list of lists to create the final DataFrame.

```
def locpapersrc_table(df):
    toflattenrows = df['location_ms'].str.split(';').apply(lambda x:[c.split(':') for c in x]).values.tolist()
    singlelistoflist = [item for sublist in toflatten for item in sublist]
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(singlelistoflist)
    return tmp
```

This version2 is slower than the first but is another method that is also very roundabout.

```
def version2(df):
   xx = df["location_ms"].str.split(';',expand = True).T
   tmp = pd.melt(xx).dropna().drop(['variable'],axis=1)['value'].str.split(':',expand=True)
   return tmp
```

Thank You!

Comment: [Please do not post code or dataframes as images, make them text please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this.

```
split_df = df['location_ms'].str.split(pat=";", expand=True)
```

Throw in something like this if you want to merge it back into the original dataframe.

```
df = df.merge(split_df, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df = df.drop('location_ms')
```

For your new problem (splitting by `;` and `:`):

```
split_df = df['location_ms'].str.split(pat=";", expand=True)
subsplit_df = pd.DataFrame(index = split_df.index)
for i in range(split_df.shape[1]):
    subsplit_df = subsplit_df.merge(split_df.iloc[:, i].str.split(pat=":", expand=True), left_index=True, right_index=True)
subsplit_df.columns = range(subsplit_df.shape[1])
```

You can merge it back in as above if you want.

Comment: You need to split by both delimiters, the  ";" and the ":"

Comment: This does not work since you have a list of lists when delimiting by both characters which then has to be manipulating into the format of the final dataframe.

Comment: "I want to split by `;` and `;` to get DataFrame B" is a direct quote from your problem. I've edited the answer to match your new criteria.

Comment: Oops sorry about that typo! If you look at the initial Dataframe and code that sentence would not make sense. Sorry about the mistake! This is more roundabout than the code that I have. You should be using apply instead of iterating through the dataframe.